# Is there a way to delete an actual target item from the table using PHP, Jquery and Ajax request as i intend herein?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP table whose data was streamed-out from the database using the foreach. However, i am trying to create a delete mechanism to it.

Here is my table :-
<?php

```
                    foreach ($projects as $projectx){
                     

                     echo '<tr>';
                        
                     echo '<th>'.$projectx['id'].'</th>';
                     echo '<td>'.$projectx['user'].'</td>';
                     echo '<td>'.$projectx['catch_code'].'</td>';
                     echo '<td>'.$projectx['user_type'].'</td>';
                     echo '<td>'.$projectx['logs'].'</td>';
                    
                     echo '<td><a href="view-details" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary view-files" data-id="'.$projectx['id'].'" data-user="'.$projectx['user'].'" data-catchcode="'.$projectx['catch_code'].'" >View</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-trash" id="remove-id" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

';
                    
                        }

**This is what i have tried so far towards it:-**

```
                     $('body').on('click', '.fa-trash', e => {
                     
                     let id = $('td .view-files').data('id');  
                     
                        if(confirm("Do you want to Remove?")){

                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: '/del.php',
                                        type: 'GET',
                                        data:{id:id},
                                        error: function(){
                                            alert("something went wromg");
                                            },
                                        success: function(e){
                                            e.preventDefault;
                                            $("#"+id).parents('tr').remove();
                                            

                                            }

                                        });

                                   
                                    }
                            });
```

Whenever i tried to delete any of the data from the table, the first data on the table is often deleted (not the intended data).

I think i am having a problem integrating/retrieving the font awesome delete class and the actual data through the IDs and classes. Please, how can i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Add class="removea" to the td for the delete

(2) Add the id value matching the db record to this td tag

In this way, when the user clicks the td tags of the delete, the system can pass the proper id for deletion by ajax.

So you are good to go using the following:

For the PHP

```
<?php
 
 echo "<table border=1 id=tblCart>";

 foreach ($projects as $projectx){
 
 echo '<tr id='  . $projectx['id'] . '>';
    
 echo '<th>'.$projectx['id'].'</th>';
 echo '<td>'.$projectx['user'].'</td>';
    
 echo '<td><a href="view-details" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary view-files" data-id="'.$projectx['id'].'" data-user="'.$projectx['user'].'" data-catchcode="'.$projectx['catch_code'].'" >View</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <td class="removea" id=' . $projectx['id'] . '><i class="fa fa-trash" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"  aria-hidden="true">Delete</i>
</td>';

    }

echo "</table>";

?>
```

For the JS

```
<script>                
$('.removea').click(function () {

var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
   
if(confirm("Do you want to Remove?")){

    $.ajax({
        url: './del.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data:{id:id},
        success: function(e){
        $('#'+id).remove();
            }  
        });
   
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I still cannot figure out why the "trash button" still does not click. When i add $('body').on('click', '.fa-trash', e => (), the button is clickable, but when i add any other classes or ID directly into the clicks , it never clicks. I don't know why. It appears very strange to me.  Do you have any idea on how i can circumvent this?

Comment: Yes, i tried your suggested answer but it does not click. Then, i tried to bring in the id='.$projectx['id'] right into the fontawesome <i tagg , then it was able to click.

But, what i notice now is that, after clicking the trash icon and deleting, the table does not get deleted immediately. But the id was sent to the database through the ajax call for deletion.

Until i refresh the table, then the database deleted row gets removed on the table. It means, it doesn't get removed from the table immediately but only through the database.

Comment: I checked your link, and its working fine over there. I don't know why mine isnt working. I am working with fontawesome though and i saw through their documentation that there are certain rules which doesn't makes trash icon clickable or workable with jquery. Maybe i am stepping on some of these rules. 

On the codes you sent to me, i copied and paste. But was not working. I noticed that you put <td class=removea.........</td> without the first <td><a.......no closing </td>....that doesn't mean anything i guess.

Comment: Oh sorry , i didn't get to you. I figured it out already though, and i decided to remove the <td....and added <a  id="'.$projectx['id'].'"<i class="fa fa-trash" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>

And this worked perfectly by calling 
$('tr td').on('click', '.fa-trash', function (){
var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
.....

Comment: This way is just similar to my suggested answer. (pass the id value) . Anyway good that you fixed the problem.